# Getting 401 in all Laravel api requests

Tags: php, laravel, rest

I'm using Laravel with Passport to secure my API with OAuth. 
Although, after using a authorized token got with PostMan tool, in all my request using the Passport middleware i'm getting 401.
I installed Laravel twice and looked all around the Internet without success and followed this page for installation: [click here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport).
There is some of my codes:

The route i'm trying to access:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){

    Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });

});
```

The auth guard:

```
'guards' => [
    //..

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

---

**Update 1: headers of request**

```
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImU5ZDcwZGY0ZjA2MGZhNDk5MzQ1ZjQyN2QxMWY1MDhkZDI2ZWQxODkzZDgxMTcxYWNkZGYxYTkxYzkwNWYxOGUyMTI2NzY0M2QwZmQyOWRiIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiZTlkNzBkZjRmMDYwZmE0OTkzNDVmNDI3ZDExZjUwOGRkMjZlZDE4OTNkODExNzFhY2RkZjFhOTFjOTA1ZjE4ZTIxMjY3NjQzZDBmZDI5ZGIiLCJpYXQiOjE1MDE1Mjc2NDYsIm5iZiI6MTUwMTUyNzY0NiwiZXhwIjoxNTMzMDYzNjQ2LCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.dbJ4jddUZx1BT9X81LQIY-Dcx6xdDtmm2nH_C6t7rgFYzRTjab6w7T1NXfzKNlAeyi4iWJAARSBDI32vCeGuAy1ukFvr0qkoEp8UIZEqeeQYYam1Oox_0fuLlJyzwkOIospEc53KZBB0AQrPpW12abxZiZ6asQ9S4AbEJa5N95QFaYRMlxPxEMQOFt28v5148-shawcmtdV-AuAOpvsmap5_f4vQ-NY9R_He0NS4zOOQEY7sPIaRrsQ_XEAJwyiGnrUyufLr02T8wDUcqTskxCtizZx0aHN8i8lz9_X7xBFMHLj4zI4R3wfuZTWlOww07HdBt1oX8PAWvTgA0lw4Sq_xeKa3-MfuCasC4Vh_KWuvHQAfTIuCQw4lPOELfWWaeJTaEuuos7YFbOdoZIHoQWVs4lcisKpHuTGd8bzIPY9GGYsG26LRZB62vX358bijUuurh8p3ajPOt45tmvJnYyaHdf1gW5YwEqbtb07bohMrLFCNhYT0JFZvKa54FRRbB6BLA4lToDA4j1secMKan8mRMLwjEhqyPD0qxBswiMc127ryQ4CLvtKZ75Weno3oAnZ29ZkgtJCTESMzFjd41K-KgrV-s9KTWvfvmOECQUTQz6xUZ5WyVLzPZdBi6wNRYdAp4xRTA1RNUH3TSAP9qYt-xWTwNANXLvL5gBkBjQM
```

PS: the token is a Personal Access Token generated with Vue component.

Comment: How are you passing the access token? Can you provide a screenshot of the postman request?

Comment: Check the update 1 @Sandeesh

Answer (score 0):

when using postman did you force the Content-Type in your header like this

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: Yes, i'm making my requests with that header. And the Authorization one too, of course.

Comment: what is your Authorization header value format? it should `Bearer <token>`

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your route file this way:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });
});
```

See more about routing [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing).

Comment: Thanks but didn't worked. I'm trying to figure it out but still without a fix.

Comment: I'm getting the token and using in header but it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

In version 5.6 and later of Laravel, cookies are no serialized/unserialized. However, Passport still expects that the cookies are serialized.

To fix this, you just need to add `Passport::withoutCookieSerialization();` to `app\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::boot()`